# What is the difference between Sum(column_name) and sum(column_name) over (partition by id)

Tags: sql, sql-server, window-functions

There is table a with two column bpm_no and total_amount. I am trying to sum up the total_amount for each bpm_no, where bpm_no can repeat and the total_amount column might be different for different rows. I am using two approach one is like below:

```
select 
    a.bpm_no,
    sum(a.total_amount)
    from table a
    group by a.bpm_no, a.total_amount
```

And another approach I am using partition by method like below:

```
    select
    a.bpm_no,
    sum(a.total_amount) over (partition by a.bpm_no)
    from table a
    group by a.bpm_no,a.total_amount
```

However, I am getting different result, using the first approach, it discard some of the values. While using the second approach, it displays every record as expected. Please explain which one is correct and whats the difference in both the approach.

Comment: The first query will give an error.

Comment: @HoneyBadger. No, I am not getting an error, but 1st query is discarding many bpm_no.

Comment: In that case I doubt you are using sql-server

Comment: I am only using sql server. But can you let me know, which query will be right one?

Comment: sql-server *will* throw an error in the first case, because you are missing a `group by` clause. If you add that, the first query is correct. It doesn't 'discard' rows, it aggregates them.

Comment: The first query will result in "*Column 'a.bpm_no' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause*" if you are really using SQL Server

Comment: Sorry, but I am already using Group by function, I just forgot to write that in the Question.

Comment: I am not getting any error after using both the above query. The only thing is the first query discard some result while second query displays every record. So, which one to use?

Comment: Both queries are wrong. In your first query, remove `a.total_amount` from the `group by`. You probably want that query (as the answerers guessed as well). In your second query, remove the `group by` all together. That will give for each occurrence of a `bpm_no` the total summed value. From your description, it doesn't sound like you are looking for that.

Comment: ' it discard some of the values...' is this a simplified query? Do you also use join in your main query?

Comment: @DT. right now its the simplified query though I will join it in another query later on but right now its a single query which is discarding some of the bpm_no only if first query is used. second query works fine. But not able to understand whats the difference, and which query to be used.

Comment: @HoneyBadger. when I remove a.total_amount it gives me an error 'Column 'a.total_amount' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause. Severity 16'

Comment: That is not possible if you only `select a.bpm_no, sum(a.total_amount)`. Please add your complete query.

Comment: @MdKamranAzam you need to post your full query, just showing part of your query is making this whole question a mess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the first Query with **GROUP BY** should fulfill your requirements

```
select a.bpm_no,
       sum(a.total_amount)
from table a
GROUP BY a.bpm_no;
```

Check [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/15467/2/0) SQLFiddle for reference

Comment: If I use this query, I will get an error to include a.total_amount in group by. And when I am using group by a.bpm_no, a.total_amount, though it gives the result, but again it discard some of the values.

Comment: it should not give the error please check the SQLfiddle i added in my answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    a.bpm_no,
    SUM(a.total_amount)
FROM 
    table a
GROUP BY 
    a.bpm_no
```

Since you are not using `group by`, its adding all the values

****DEMO****

> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/bb29b/2

Comment: Will this work, as it gives me an error to also include a.total_amount in group by and when I am doing that, result discard some of the bpm_no.

Comment: This should work. You cannot include `a.total_amount` in `group by` clause as you want to aggregate that column

Comment: I have added a sqlfiddle link with some random data. Please check if thats the output u want.

Answer (score -1):

In The First Query You Should Edit Group By Clause As Following.

```
select 
    a.bpm_no,
    sum(a.total_amount)
    from table a
    group by a.bpm_no
```

In The Second Case Result Will Be Following.

```
select
    a.bpm_no,
    sum(a.total_amount) over (partition by a.bpm_no)
    from table a
    group by a.bpm_no
```

In The All Query Column Use With Aggregate Not Use In Group By Clause.